# How to write a polymorphic function with a fixed type in one argument

Tags: haskell, polymorphism

I want write a polymorphic function (e.g. mod) with a fixed type in the second argument, the type of the return value is determined by the first argument.
Here is my implementation:

```
f :: Integral a => a -> Int -> a
f n m = mod n m
```

and it got error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘Int’
  ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      f :: forall a. Integral a => a -> Int -> a
```

If I don't want to write two functions with specific type of the first argument (f1 :: Int -> Int -> Int and f2 :: Integer -> Int -> Integer), is there a more elegant implementation?

Comment: if you give it the `Integer -> Int -> Integer` type it also won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mod` requires both its arguments to be of the same type. So, use [`fromIntegral`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral) to convert `m` from an `Int` to type `a`:

```hs
f :: Integral a => a -> Int -> a
f n m = mod n (fromIntegral m)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. However, I still don't understand why Integral and Int are different types, but Num (fromIntegral convert Int m to Num m) and Integral are the same?

Comment: @tkrd `Integral` and `Num` are typeclasses, not types. `Int` is a type though. See [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses) for an introduction

Comment: @tkrd `Integral` and `Num` are **typeclasses** ([read more here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses)), not types.